# How do I transform a data table column from cumulative to difference when reading CSV into spring boot application?

Tags: sql, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, window-functions

I have data in a table like

```
   date  | city | Cumulative total 
---------------------------------
1/1/2020 | NYC  |    10
1/2/2020 | NYC  |    15
1/3/2020 | NYC  |    31
1/4/2020 | NYC  |    36
1/5/2020 | NYC  |    55
 .
 .  // more data for NYC continued
 .
1/1/2020 | BER  |    1
1/2/2020 | BER  |    5
1/3/2020 | BER  |    13
1/4/2020 | BER  |    42
1/5/2020 | BER  |    45
 .
 .  // more data for BER continued
 .
```

I want this data to not hold the `cumulative`, but rather hold the `difference`. Basically I want to subtract the next day from the day before it, making sure that the cities match up.

```
   date  | city | Cumulative total 
---------------------------------
1/1/2020 | NYC  |    10
1/2/2020 | NYC  |    5
1/3/2020 | NYC  |    16
1/4/2020 | NYC  |    5
1/5/2020 | NYC  |    19
 .
 .  // more data for NYC continued
 .
1/1/2020 | BER  |    1
1/2/2020 | BER  |    4
1/3/2020 | BER  |    8
1/4/2020 | BER  |    29
1/5/2020 | BER  |    3
 .
 .  // more data for BER continued
 .
```

I have the data within a CSV and am to load it into a database for a spring boot application. However, the spring boot application needs the difference, not the cumulative. How can I properly transform this data either

1. Within the database upon reading the data from the CSV?
2. By writing a special query within the `JpaRepository` so that my POJO's come back as the transformed data?

I have no idea how to implement either of the previous, but they are my ideas for what to do. I ask that someone help me see what the most "industry standard" way to handle this situation is. Maybe there is a better way than what I proposed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database supports window functions, this is an easy task for `lag()`, which lets you access any column on the *previous* row, given a `partition` and `order by` specification:

```
select 
    t.*,
    cumulative 
        - lag(cumulative, 1, 0) over(partition by city order by date) as difference
from mytable t
```

Not all databases support the 3-argument form of `lag()`, in which case you can do:

```
select
    t.*,
    coalesce(
        cumulative - lag(cumulative) over(partition by city order by date),
        cumulative
    ) difference
from mytable t
```